# Get client_id/client_secret From Tesla Motors API

Tags: oauth

I'm making an app to keep track of things like miles driven, Kwh used, etc. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get a client_id and client_secret being that the API is unofficial.

Here's the Apiary with the API details:
http://docs.timdorr.apiary.io/#reference/authentication/tokens/get-an-access-token?console=1

Anyone know how to generate them? or is everyone else that makes an app for an unofficial API just making a random string for those?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the Smartcar's API! The cliend_id and client_secret appear on your dashboard once you sign up (https://smartcar.com), it is very easy to find them. The API also allows you to do other stuff like locking and unlocking the tesla, finding the location, etc.

You can also check the Odometer API endpoint page to learn more about how you can get the miles driven here (https://smartcar.com/product/odometer/).

Answer (score 1):

The *apiary* web site tells you to use the following values.

```
"client_id”: "81527cff06843c8634fdc09e8ac0abefb46ac849f38fe1e431c2ef2106796384",
"client_secret": "c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3",
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody finds this helpful I'm adding this info:
Tesla API has changed its auth process in 2021, and as per the [unofficial documentation](https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/api-basics/authentication), the first step is to get the login page in which user authenticates. For this, only client_id is needed and it is always `"ownerapi"`. There is no longer a client_secret query param.